# How do you find out which version of Gnome Desktop ships with a certain version of Ubuntu without installation?

Tags: gnome, package-management

How do you most reliably and accurately correlate which version of GNOME Desktop a certain version of Ubuntu ships with, without installing that version of Ubuntu? I'm referring here to more recent versions of Ubuntu, e.g. 18.04 and up.

I'd like to know either what version comes with the base version of Ubuntu, or, any patch version that comes with the official updates for that version of Ubuntu.

Using the `rmadison` command from [Debian's developer scripts package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/devscripts) I don't fully follow what is the answer to my question ― I see nothing for Focal Fossa (20.04) in the outputs:

On Ubuntu 20.04:

```
$ sudo apt install devscripts  
...
$ rmadison gnome

 gnome | 1:3.0+6ubuntu3  | precise/universe | amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 gnome | 1:3.8+4ubuntu3  | trusty/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 gnome | 1:3.14+3ubuntu1 | xenial/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 gnome | 1:3.22+9        | bionic/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 gnome | 1:3.30+1ubuntu1 | disco/universe   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 gnome | 1:3.30+2        | eoan/universe    | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 gnome | 1:3.30+2        | focal/universe   | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 gnome | 1:3.30+2        | groovy/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
```

---

```
$ rmadison gnome-desktop

 gnome-desktop | 1:2.32.1-0ubuntu9 | precise         | source
 gnome-desktop | 1:2.32.1-2ubuntu1 | trusty/universe | source
```

I think this command-line tool pretty much mirrors the same information that's available on a launchpad search [for GNOME Desktop](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-desktop), which which does not explicitly relate to Focal Fossa, and neither does Launchpad relate to GNOME in general for Focal Fossa, assuming I am searching Launchpad well.

Comment: Are the close votes an indication that using the rmadison command from the devscripts pacakge (as suggested on the supposedly linked duplicate) is the canonical answer to this question? I have edited my question to show why the solution to that other question does not seem to satisfy this one.

Comment: Isn't the 7th line of the output in the first block the one you're looking for? If not, I am confused about what you want...

Comment: Ah cool, right. But I'm not sure about gnome-desktop yet (the results are blank for Focal Fossa for it in my second command above).

Comment: The reason for that is that there is no `gnome-desktop` package for 20.04 or any supported release. I didn't realise this when I made my first comment. The package you want to search for is, I think `gnome-shell`. By the way you may find https://packages.ubuntu.com useful (the answer to the linked question that suggests searching there was recently undeleted, so you may not have seen it).

Comment: Thanks @Zanna. And I like the words in there: "graphical shell for the GNOME desktop". Maybe they decided to stop calling the thing 'GNOME Desktop' or some other reorganization of what's packaged under what name. Graphical Shell sounds cool to me!